# how to read pcap file, filter by ip address and port then write data to another file

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

As part of a lab exercise that I am doing, I have been asked; **using tcpdump read the packets from tcpdumpep1.pcap and filter packets from IP address 184.107.41.72 and port 80. Write these packets to a new file**

I tried the following, but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
$ tcpdump -r tcpdumpep1.pcap -w output.txt host 184.107.41.72 port 80
reading from file tcpdumpep1.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
tcpdump: syntax error in filter expression: syntax error
```

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: tcpdump -r tcpdumpep1.pcap -w output.txt host 184.107.41.72 port 80

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tcpdump takes a filter **predicate**, meaning it expects a logic expression with a boolean value once executed on a packet.

Here, it returns a syntax error because **you're missing a logical and**:

```
tcpdump -r tcpdumpep1.pcap -w output.txt host 184.107.41.72 and port 80
```

Comment: tcpdump -r tcpdumpep1.pcap && host 184.107.41.72 and port 80 -w output.txt  ??

Comment: No, just the command I provided, with the `and` should suffice.

Comment: Thank you, sir. So I wasn't a million miles off the correct answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help! Do you want me to change anything to accept the answer?

Comment: No thats it all sorted. Thanks again.